# Calling asp.net page method from javascript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery, pagemethods

I am using PageMethod w/ javascript to call server-side code:

```
 function getMonths() {

   PageMethods.BindMonthlyPeriods(getMonthsSuccess, onFailure);            }
 }

 function getMonthsSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {

    var picker = document.getElementById("monthPicker");

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        var newOption = document.createElement('option');
        newOption.text = result[i];
        newOption.value = result[i];

        picker.add(newOption); 
    }
}
```

With this in code-behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string[] BindMonthlyPeriods()
    {

    }
```

This works fine in IE / Chrome but not in firefox. No specific error msg the data just doesnt populate in firefox.

Ive also tried using a jQuery ajax call instead but that isnt working, though I'm not sure I've done it correctly:

```
 function getMonths() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.aspx/BindMonthlyPeriods",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            var picker = document.getElementById("monthPicker");

            for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {

                var newOption = document.createElement('option');
                newOption.text = result[i];
                newOption.value = result[i];

                picker.add(newOption);
            }

        }
    });
```

EDIT

Using Firebug I did not find any error msgs in the Net tab but did find this error in the Console tab:

uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame :: http://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/.../page.aspx :: getMonthsSuccess :: line 251" data: no]

Comment: @Sean , can you use firebug and check what is the problem , it clearly shows the error in the ajax

Comment: The jQuery ajax call isnt working in IE either. I think id rather use the jquery approach rather than the PageMethod approach. Ill check firebug.

Comment: @sean , use firebug to debug ,we can easily find the problem , see the resonse in net tab.

Comment: @sean is your method require any arguments , if so it is failing there

Comment: The method doesnt have any parameters, just returns a string[].

Comment: @sean it is throwing error regarding arguments only , if you want you can pass them through data {} and access them as query string.

Comment: It says line 251 which I believe is this code: picker.add(newOption); The add method shows (element, before) as parameters to the method not sure what 'before' is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding null parameter to the 'add' method of the monthpicker:

picker.add(newOption, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
< asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
                OnClientClick="return saveChanges()" />   **Script:**  var isPostBack=false; function saveChanges() { if(!isPostBack){
         PageMethods.savePageChanges(tableData, updateContent_OnSucceeded,      updateContent_onFailure);
  return false;
  }else{ 
     return true;}
   }




    function updateContent_OnSucceeded(retval) {
       isPostBack=true;
      $('# <%=btnSave.ClientID%>).click();
    }

    function updateContent_onFailure(val) {
        alert("Error: " + val.get_message());

    }**CS:**[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool savePageChanges(List<List<string>> rowDataArraySeries)
{}
```